# Generating multiple lists to hold data from a for loop

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have runs scored and runs allowed data for each baseball team stored in a list; here are 3 team's data:

```
> str(d)
List of 3
 $ : num [1:32, 1:2] 2 2 3 4 6 3 2 14 5 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "R" "RA"
  ..- attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  num [1:134] 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 ...
 $ : num [1:33, 1:2] 0 3 3 2 0 8 6 7 4 6 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "R" "RA"
  ..- attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  num [1:133] 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 ...
 $ : num [1:35, 1:2] 1 0 7 2 6 1 5 7 0 3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "R" "RA"
  ..- attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  num [1:131] 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 ...
```

I am running a simulation where I sample each team's runs scored and compare that to their runs allowed.  I then store the results in a list.  Here is the for loop:

```
z <- list()
for(i in 1:length(d)){
  s <- sample(d[[i]][, 1], length(d[[i]][, 1]), replace = TRUE)
  while(any(ind <- s == d[[i]][, 2])) 
    s[ind] <- sample(d[[i]][, 1], sum(ind), replace = TRUE)
  wins <- sum(s > d[[i]][, 2])
  losses <- length(d[[i]][, 1]) - wins
  win_perc <- wins/length(d[[i]][, 1])

  z[[i]] <- c(wins, losses, win_perc)
}
```

I am wondering how to run the for loop thousands of times and return the data to one list for each team.  For example, when I run the simulation on the Cubs' data I want to do so 1000 times and return all of those results to one list.  Then I want to move on to the next team and do the same.  So in the end there are 30 team lists with 1000 rows in each.  Here is what the list looks like:

```
> z
[[1]]
[1] 16.0 16.0  0.5

[[2]]
[1] 13.0000000 20.0000000  0.3939394

[[3]]
[1] 21.0 14.0  0.6
```

Would I need to use the replicate function?

Comment: 1) If you want to loop over a list, you should use `lapply`, which will do so more efficiently than your `for` loop. Your loop grows an object, which is one of the slowest operations you can do. 2) You seem to have a list of matrices. I think you could write much more efficient code, if you restructured your data into one data.table. The output should also be a data.table. 3) As always, it would be easier to answer this if you provided reproducible data, i.e., `dput(d)`. A verbal description of your simulation would also be nice.

Comment: I will take your advice and try it out using data.table instead